# I need to iterate through a dictionary and see if keys are in a given list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Given a dictionary d and a list lst, remove all elements from the dictionary whose key is an element of lst. Any elements from the list that are NOT keys of the dictionary should be added to a new set associated with the variable  not_found. For example, given the dictionary {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8} and the list [1, 6, 7], the resulting dictionary would be {3:4, 5:6} and the set not_found would contain 6.

this is what my code looks like:

```
not_found = ()
for i in d:
 if d[i] in lst:
    not_found.append(d[i])
            del d[i]
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to delete elements of any `dict` while you are iterating over it. Also, you would be better off iterating over `lst` rather than the dictionary `d` to take advantage of its constant time lookup. The way you are doing it now is to iterate over the dict then iterate over the list, *each time*. This isn't ideal. Try something like,

```
not_found = set()
for e in lst:
    if e in d:
        del d[e]
    else:
        not_found.add(e)

print d          # {3: 4, 5: 6}
print not_found  # set([6])
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting from a list/dict while iterating over it will cause you to skip over items. `dict` should complain if the size changes while you are iterating over it.

Usually it's best to create a new dict with the items you need to keep

In your case it's netter to iterate over `lst` instead

```
>>> d =  {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}
>>> lst = [1, 6, 7]
>>> not_found = {k for k in lst if k not in d}
>>> for k in lst:
...    if k in d:
...        del d[k]
>>> d
{3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in lst:
 if i in d:
  del d[i]
```